# jQuery mobile count bubble with radio button

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a series of radio buttons that I wish to show a count value for similar to the list view count bubble. Can this be done using the framework?

I have tried using the following -

```
<input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1" value="30" checked="checked" />
<label for="radio1">Blank<span class="ui-li-count">30</span></label>
```

Basically it is just to show the `value` of each radio item.

Thanks

*Edit*

I wish to show a value to the far right of each radio button that I have. Very much like the way count bubble is used for list-items.

example of the list-item count bubble [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/lists/lists-count.html)

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? Your question is unclear

Comment: I'm not getting **what you currently have?** and **what do you want to achieve?** And I read the question three times.

Comment: I have edited to explain, hopefully a little better with example of what I am tryign to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to add ul tag with data-role="listview" attribute and then include inside the li tag the select and span like this

```
<div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li>
            <select>
                <option>select</option>
                ..
            </select>
            <span class="ui-li-count">23</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```